# How to convert an Activity to FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

So far this is what I attempted. This is from the Activity that sets up the fragments. This is the method for loading the fragments.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
      Fragment f = new Fragment();
      FragmentActivity fa = new FragmentActivity();

      switch(i){
      case 0:
         f=News.newInstance(_context);
      break;    
      case 1:
         f=Info.newInstance(_context);
      break;
      case 2:
         //f=Info.newInstance(_context);
         fa=Files.newInstance(_context);
      break;
      case 3:
         f=Donate.newInstance(_context);
      break;
}
```

Next I setup the Files class so that it can load the Activity via me converting it to `FragmentActivity`. I dont want to use a `ListFragment`, as I want to make some button and set the `onclicklistener` for them.

```
public class Files extends FragmentActivity {

      private ListView m_listview;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.files);

        m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_list_view);

        String[] items = new String[] {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
          new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        m_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

    public static FragmentActivity newInstance(Context _context) {
         Files f = new Files();

            return f;
    }
}
```

Right now when I run the app, there are no errors, nothing in the stack trace, and when I hit the tab to load that `FragmentActivity`, its just blank. I tried removing the `listview` and all, and just put a `textview` in the XML layout and that doesn't even appear when I attempt it.

Comment: you should concentrate more on java syntax learning, not only on android. You are making basic mistakes here that have big impacts on an Android app. I am thinking about creating a fragment for nothing or the horrible static thing at the end of your question.

Comment: If I had a $ for every time I'd explained the following I'd be rich...`FragmentActivity fa = new FragmentActivity();` - You can NOT create an instance of any class which extends `Activity` using `new`.